# Storing URLs with greek characters in the IDTable

Tags: multilingual

I have some code which stores custom URLs in the IDTable.
I am experiencing an issue with a site using the Greek language (el-GR) when part of the URL contains Greek characters e.g. `χρώμα`. My code contains the following where the variable key contains the string "χρώμα":

```
IDTableProvider provider = GetProvider();
var entry = new IDTableEntry(prefix, key, id, parentID, customData);
provider.Add(entry);
```

When reading the IDTable entry back out of the table I get "???µa".

I looked at the code in dotPeek and found that Sitecore is doing a regular insert from the add method, so I tried doing something directly in SSMS:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[IDTable]
SET [Key] = 'χρώμα'
WHERE ID = '{205DBEAC-B679-4CC8-804C-90AF6201EDB2}'
```

And I got the same result, so the issue must be in SQL Server. I noticed that the field type is `varchar(255)` rather than nvarchar(255) which I'm assuming is the reason for the problem. Is there any way to work around this limitation, perhaps encoding the string before saving/adding to the IDTable?

Comment: Maybe the collation of your database is not capable of storing these characters. Run `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('SITECORE_MASTER', 'Collation') SQLCollation;` to find out what the collation is.

Comment: I don't really want to play around with the database, as that is not supported by Sitecore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer would be, to just update the field to NVARCHAR - from an application layer perspective, nothing in Sitecore should really care about this.

That said; I understand the reasons for not wanting to do this.

Your alternative then, becomes to convert in and out of Unicode when adding and getting keys. There are a number of ways to achieve this; I propose BASE64.

### Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

### Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

And you would then need to update your code.

```
IDTableProvider provider = GetProvider();
var entry = new IDTableEntry(prefix, Base64Encode(key), id, parentID, customData);
provider.Add(entry);
```

And also when getting, obviously.

Base64 snippet sourced here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string

**edited to add**

You could of course write your own version of `Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerIDTable` and configure it here. I've never done it, and it seems way too much work for what it would be worth.

```
  <IDTable type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)IDTable, Sitecore.Kernel" singleInstance="true">
    <param connectionStringName="master" />
    <param desc="cacheSize">2500KB</param>
  </IDTable>
```

You would need to override the following methods:

- public override void Add(IDTableEntry entry)
- public override void Add(IDTableEntry entry)
- public override IDTableEntry GetID(string prefix, string key)
- public override IDTableEntry[] GetKeys(string prefix, ID id)
- public override IDTableEntry[] GetKeys(string prefix)
- public override void Remove(string prefix, string key)

Doesn't seem worth it, in my opinion.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion also! Thanks